# Select rows that equals to 10 digit

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, string-function

I've a table called *idx* with following data

```
id dex          
-- ------------ 
1  Major 12354  
2  CITY 541 DER 
3  9987741221   
4  7845741      
5  789456 2121
```

how to select rows with only digits and it should 10 digits only

expected output is

```
id dex         
-- ----------- 
3  9987741221  
5  789456 2121
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to match your criteria `^[0-9]{10,10}$`, and I've used `replace()` function to remove empty space between characters(*dex in id 5*)

```
select * 
from idx 
where replace(dex,' ','')~'^[0-9]{10,10}$' -- or '^[0-9]{10,}$'
```

---

`^[0-9]{10,10}$` :

**`[0-9]`** - *To get digits*

**`{10,10}$`** - *Maximum and minimum value in selected string in your case both are `10`*

---

***`OR`***

Using `char_length()`

```
select *
from idx 
where  dex~'^[0-9]' 
       and char_length(replace(dex,' ','')) = 10
```

Comment: `{10,10}` can be replaced with `{10}`